# Adding samba user programically with node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, samba

I've wrote function in node,js as follows:

```
const addUserToSamba = (userLogin, password) => {

         const echoPassword = spawnSync('echo', ['ne',`${password}\n${password}\n`]);

         const addUserCredentialsToSamba = spawnSync('smbpasswd', ['-a', '-s', userLogin], {
                 input: echoPassword.stdout,
         });

         console.log('Added user credentials to Samba configuration');
         console.log(addUserCredentialsToSamba.stderr.toString());
         console.log(addUserCredentialsToSamba.stdout.toString());
}
```

I want to achieve something like this in bash:

```
echo -ne "$PASS\n$PASS\n" | smbpasswd -a -s $LOGIN
```

When I'm running `addUserToSamba(userLogin, password);` function with given userlLogin and user password then I even get message `Added user ${userLogin}` as a stdout of the addUserCredentialsToSamba outcome.

But the credentials don't work.

Have I correctly rewritten this bash function to the node.js one?
If no, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply skip the `echo` part and output the credentials directly to the `smbpasswd` process:

```
const addUserCredentialsToSamba = spawnSync('smbpasswd', ['-a', '-s', userLogin], {
    input: `${password}\n${password}\n`,
});
```